# How to Parsing JSON Array file withOuth name?

Tags: parsing, android-listview, json

Pleas Expert help me..!!

I have a Json some like this

```
["google.com","youtube.com","facebook.com","tweeter.com","instagram.com"]
```

And i need to display in ListView.

Pleas Help..!!
And Thaks.

Comment: I just need to display in ListView, i'm new in android...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can finish it by yourself with the following code

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {

                    //JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                        //JSONObject arry = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        ListFA data = new ListFA();
                        data.setName(response.get(i).toString());
                        forbidlist.add(data);

                    } 
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

            }
        });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```